# Unicorn tag - potential conflict

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [unicorn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unicorn) tag could mean one of two things: the U-series codename for 14.10, or the prefork server that can be used in conjunction with other webservers.

It looks like there's edits in the tag wikis for Unicorn to be the latter of those two, but [unicorn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unicorn) is marked now as a synonym of [14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/14.10) as done by fossfreedom.  But this may cause any number of confusing issues since the preexisting tag seems to have been the prefork server.

Is it a problem that we've got two things that're both on topic here, but the tag will be in conflict?  Or have we got a resolution for this?

Comment: Did we have a unicorn tag all this time and I didn't knew it?!

Answer (score 11):

No questions are linked to "unicorn".

So we can delete the tag wiki if required and then make it a synonym.

Seems like a perfect synonym for 14.10 - unlike "trusty" questions I would expect both "utopic" and "unicorn" questions popping up for obvious reasons.

For the moment I've unlinked the unicorn synonym.  If you would like to make unicorn a synonym of 14.10 - upvote.  Similarly, downvote if you consider we'll be getting an influx of the "prefork server" soon and prefer to keep "unicorn" separate.

Comment: We should synonymize it to prevent confusion. If we need a unicorn server tag make `unicorn-server` or similar.

Comment: @Seth nah, just stick with numbers anyways.

Comment: @Braiam If we do that we end up with tons of the same tags being created and killed and created and killed and we'll get misuse of the unicorn tag.

Comment: @Seth I presume the +300 rep users should know that they don't need to create another tag if there's one that already covers the topic.

Comment: @Braiam You'd think, but they don't.

Comment: @Seth and that's why I say that tagging sucks because we make it suck.

Comment: Unrelated, but some people tag their questions with "installation" and not "system-installation" or "software-installation".

Comment: @saiarcot895 actually the system suggests installation [based in a semi-bayesian reasoning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/206907/213575) to select the tags.